# Import / export oracle scheme with correct character set

Tags: oracle, import, export

I have exported a scheme successfully. On the import however the log says that the character sets don't match. The strange thing is that on the server the export was done the character set is the same as on the target database.

This is from the source:

```
SQL> select * from v$NLS_PARAMETERS
  2  ;


**NLS_CHARACTERSET
WE8MSWIN1252**

**NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET
AL16UTF16**
```

And this is from the log of the import:

```
Importvorgang mit Zeichensatz WE8MSWIN1252 und Zeichensatz AL16UTF16 NCHAR durchgeführt
Export-Client verwendet Zeichensatz US7ASCII  (mögliche Zeichensatzkonvertierung)
```

Why is the dump recognized as US7ASCII set? The source and target both are non-US machines.

Thank you

Comment: Locks like the Client where import/export was executed is set to US7ASCII. Check the target database for some special characters (e.g. üöä). Maybe you can test with a small single table only.

Comment: The german Umalute are missing. ü went u, ö went o, etc.

Comment: Try to set your local environment to WE8MSWIN1252 or similar, e.g. `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_GERMANY.AL32UTF8`. It is not required to use the same but the characterset must cover all characters from CP1252.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Looks like issue with char set of client session. Set it to globally supported and recommended UTF8 format.

Pls take the export again and try importing. (Do the following before export):

```
In Windows
    set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
In Unix
    export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
```

These days DB char set is also recommended to be 'AL32UTF8'.